# find values of custom attribute in html using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visualforce

[Click here for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmFUo.png)

Inside loop of `{listOfValue}`
i want to find different column values filtered by data-week = {listofvalueObject}
and want to add data in each row based on column segregated by this data-week attributes value.

I have assigned the values form a list so it every column has different data-week value.

I have tried :

```
var allColumnValClass = j$('.columnVal').filter('[data-week]');

var allColumnValClass = j$('.columnVal').filter('[data-week='Something dynamic ']');
```

Comment: Please provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select them like this:

`var allColumnValClass = j$('.columnVal[data-week]')`

and

`var allColumnValClass = j$('.columnVal[data-week="' + Something dynamic + '"]')`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='columnVal' data-week="1"></div>
<div class='columnVal' data-week="2"></div>
<div class='columnVal' data-week="3"></div>

<script>

    var dataList = $(".columnVal").map(function () {
        return $(this).data("week");
    }).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
        console.log(dataList[i]);
    }
</script>
```

cheers